# Encrypting the message but not able to decrypt in android

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

I am having three activities.In `MainActivity`,I have two buttons which allow me to choose from two options I.e click on `encrypt` to go to`EncryptActivity.java` and click on `decrypt` to go on `DecryptActivity.java`.

In first activity I.e. `EncryptActivity`,I am encrypting the message written by the user in the `EditText`. Then I press `back` button to go to main menu and then I click on `decrypt` button to enter into second activity `DecryptActivity.java` to decrypt the message and print the message in a textview.

But the problem is when I click on `decrypt` button in `DecryptActivity`,nothing gets printed in the `Textview`.

EncryptActivity.java:

```
public class EncryptActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText ed1;
Button b1;

private ClipboardManager myClipboard;
private ClipData myClip;
KeyGenerator keygenerator;
static SecretKey secretkey;

Cipher cipher;
byte[] encrypted;
String encryptedText = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.encrypt_activity);
    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    myClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text = ed1.getText().toString();//now encrypt the message
            try {
                keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Blowfish");
                secretkey = keygenerator.generateKey();
                Log.d("asd", secretkey.toString());
                cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretkey);
                encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
                encryptedText = encrypted.toString();
                myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", encryptedText);
                myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text Copied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

DecryptActivity.java:

```
public class DecryptActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText ed1;
TextView tv;
Button b1,b2;
byte[] decrypted;
String decryptedText = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.decrypt_activity);
    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.decrypteditText);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.decryptbutton);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("asd","inside onclick");
            try {
                Log.d("asd","inside try of decryptActivity");
                KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Blowfish");
                SecretKey secretkey = keygenerator.generateKey();
                Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
                  cipher2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,secretkey);
                Log.d("asd","in decrypt key is"+secretkey.toString());
                Log.d("asd","before getBytes");
                byte[] encrypted =ed1.getText().toString().getBytes();
                Log.d("asd",ed1.getText().toString());
                decrypted = cipher2.doFinal(encrypted);
                tv=(EditText)findViewById((R.id.textView));
                tv.setText("Asd");
                Log.d("asd",new String(decrypted));
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text Pasted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: ciphertext is binary data. It is a mistake to represent it as a String without encoding like Hex or Base64. Moreover, `encrypted.toString()` isn't doing what you think.

Comment: @ Henry ,but ` `encrypted.toString()`  is printing the encrypted message in the Logcat.

Comment: You will see that it is not printing the content if you try some long byte[] and observe that the result is still short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a symmetric krypto algorithm like Blowfish it is essential that the encryption and the decryption have to use the same key - otherwise the decryption will fail.

In your case you generate a random key before encrypting and again before decrypting:

```
 KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Blowfish");
 SecretKey secretkey = keygenerator.generateKey();
```

Therefore you are trying to decrypt with a different key! By definition this can not work...

For encrypting you can generate a new key but then you have to save it and use it again for decrypting.

Additionally you make the mistake that a `byte[]` can not be converted to a String by calling it's `toString()` method. Convert it to a hex or base64 string otherwise it will never work.

Comment: @ Robert,what if i send the encrypted message to another phone ,then there while decrypting this message i will be forced to make an object of  `SecretKey` again. What to do in such a scenario ?

Comment: Use a `SecretKeySpec` instead.